# Eliminating excess synchronization and improving error handling when updating a shared variable

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, exception, synchronization

I have a shared object that caches the results of database queries whose interface is "get cached results" and "invalidate cached results."  It is acceptable to return slightly stale data.

My current solution is pasted at the bottom of this question.  Each cache's `get` and `clear` method is accessible via a public method in `CacheService`.  Within `Cache`, `lastUpdated` contains the most recent query results; `isValid` indicates whether the results should be updated; `updateGuard` is used to ensure that only one thread updates the results; and `updateWait` lets threads wait for another thread to update the results.  To ensure progress and because it is acceptable to return slightly stale data, after `lastUpdated` is updated I immediately return its results from the updating threads and all threads waiting on the update - I do not check to see if `isValid` has been set to `false` again.

---

**Major concern**: if `lastUpdated = getUpdate()` throws an exception (likely the result of a network failure when trying to talk to the database) then presently I'm simply returning `lastUpdated` - it is acceptable to return slightly stale data, but repeated transient faults during `getUpdate()` could result in extremely stale data.  I want to include some logic along the lines of

```
final int maxRetries = 5;
...
try {
  updateWait.drainPermits();
  int retryCount = 0;
  while(true) {
    try {
      lastUpdated = getUpdate();
      break;
    } catch(Exception e) {
      retryCount++;
      if(retryCount == maxRetries) {
        throw Exception e in all threads waiting on semaphore
      }
    }
  }
  isValid = true;
}
```

However I'm not sure of a good way to implement "throw Exception e in all threads waiting on semaphore" or if there's a better alternative.  One option I've considered is to use a Scala `Try`, i.e. `Try<ImmutableList<T>> lastUpdated`, but I'm trying not to mix Scala and Java objects where possible in order to make code maintenance easier.

---

**Less Major Concern**: Right now I've got three synchronization variables (isValid, updateGuard, updateWait) which seems excessive - I'm looking for a way to safely eliminate one or two of these.

---

```
public class CacheService {
  private final Cache<Foo> fooCache;
  private final Cache<Bar> barCache;
  // and so on

  private abstract class Cache<T> {
    private final AtomicBoolean updateGuard = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final Semaphore updateWait = new Semaphore(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    private volatile boolean isValid = true;
    private volatile ImmutableList<T> lastUpdated = getUpdate();

    protected abstract ImmutableList<T> getUpdate();

    public void clear() {
      isValid = false;
    }

    public ImmutableList<T> get() {
      if(isValid) {
        return lastUpdated;
      } else {
        if(updateGuard.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
          try {
            updateWait.drainPermits();
            lastUpdated = getUpdate();
            isValid = true;
          } finally {
            updateGuard.set(false);
            updateWait.release(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
          }
        } else {
          while(updateGuard.get()) {
            try {
              updateWait.acquire();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return lastUpdated;
      }
    }
  }

  public CacheService() {
    fooCache = new Cache<Foo>() {
      @Override
      protected ImmutableList<Foo> getUpdate() {
        return // database query
      }
    };
    // Likewise when initializing barCache etc
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) and [`completeExceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeExceptionally-java.lang.Throwable-)

```
private abstract static class Cache<T> {
    private final AtomicReference<CompletableFuture<ImmutableList<T>>> value = 
        new AtomicReference<>();
    private static final int MAX_TRIES = 5;

    protected abstract ImmutableList<T> getUpdate();

    public void clear() {
        value.getAndUpdate(f -> f != null && f.isDone() ? null : f);
        // or value.set(null); if you want the cache to be invalidated while it is being updated.
    }

    public ImmutableList<T> get() {
        CompletableFuture<ImmutableList<T>> f = value.get();
        if (f != null) {
            try {
                return f.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        f = new CompletableFuture<>();
        if (!value.compareAndSet(null, f)) {
            return get();
        }
        for(int tries = 0; ; ){
            try {
                ImmutableList<T> update = getUpdate();
                f.complete(update);
                return update;
            } catch (Exception e){
                if(++tries == MAX_TRIES){
                    f.completeExceptionally(e);
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to handle the exceptions differently, and you will need to clear it after an exception is thrown if you want to try to get the update again.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation has a problem. When 100 threads stall on the updateGuard lock, all the threads will execute the getUpdate() path. So, once you have the lock, you need to recheck isValid.

I am not the expert for the Semphore class, but I think combining the updateGuard and the updateWait should be feasible.

Here is just the stripped down version of your get method body:

```
while (!isValid) {
  if (updateWait.tryAcquire()) {
    if (!isValid) {
      lastUpdate = getUpdate();
      isValid = true;
    }
  } else {
    updateWait.acquire();
  }
  updateWait.release();
}
return lastUpdate;
```

This should have all the semantics from your code, plus rechecking isValid.

Exception: Within the Java Caching library [cache2k](http://cache2k.org) we implemented Exception caching. I wrote a blog entry on this, see: [About caching exception](http://cruftex.net/2014/12/07/About-caching-exceptions.html). This may address some of your issues.

At the bottom line, this is my summary on it:

- Fail-fast and always propagate an exception if you cannot do anything useful.
- Fail-fast means no retry whatsoever to get rid of blocked resources as soon as possible. The user will retry in any case: on failure or when waiting time gets too long.
- When you propagate the exception don't log it as warning additionally.
- If you rethrow one exception from a data source to multiple consumers, make sure you explicitly make clear that these exceptions are duplicates
- As soon as you return outdated data, because the recent request returns Exceptions, make sure to have a warning mechanism. In cache2k we probably will implement two metrics which say: how many seconds are overdue and how many entries are affected